# After firing my bullet sprite in Ebitengine, I cannot do it independently, continued below

Tags: go

I am writing a game with ebitengine and I could not figure out the firing logic. Whenever I press the fire button, my bullet follows my sprite. For example, after firing, whenever I move up, down, right or left, the fired bullet moves the same way.

```
        s := Pos{
        p1X: float64(g.player1.x)/unit + 50,
        p1Y: float64(g.player1.y)/unit + 50,
    }

    newBullet(float64(g.player1.x)/unit+50,
        float64(g.player1.y)/unit+50)

    s2 := Pos2{
        p2X: float64(g.player2.x)/unit + 50,
        p2Y: float64(g.player2.y)/unit + 50,
    }
    newBullet(float64(g.player2.x)/unit+50,
        float64(g.player2.y)/unit+50)

    op := &ebiten.DrawImageOptions{}
    op.GeoM.Scale(2, 2)
    op.GeoM.Translate(s.p1X, s.p1Y)
    op.GeoM.Translate(float64(g.bullet[0].p1X), float64(g.bullet[0].p1Y))
    screen.DrawImage(ebitenBullet, op)

    opt := &ebiten.DrawImageOptions{}
    opt.GeoM.Scale(2, 2)
    opt.GeoM.Translate(s2.p2X, s2.p2Y)
    opt.GeoM.Translate(float64(g.bullet2[0].p2X), float64(g.bullet2[0].p2Y))
    screen.DrawImage(ebitenBullet2, opt)
```

I used this and it is not working in my aspiration

I tried to copy X and Y to struct and I try to get my sprites position (live position) but it's following my sprite.

Comment: It's hard to understand what your code does. It is not clear what the newBullet() function does. I think in Draw() you create a new struct with each frame.